# Getting the error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment doesn't have view associated with it or the view has been destroyed"

Tags: kotlin

моё приложение это приложение визит,  с тремя фрагментами первое это групповой чат  второй это список пользователей третий это история визита пользователя. Моя проблема когда я пишу в чат а потом перехожу между фрагментами мое приложение вылетает.  Когда я убираю код логики ввода текста тогда ошибки нет . Помогите пожалуйста я начинающий разработчик

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MessengerFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentMessengerBinding, MessengerViewModel>(
    R.layout.fragment_messenger
) {
    override val binding by viewBinding(FragmentMessengerBinding::bind)
    override val viewModel by viewModels<MessengerViewModel>()
    private val messAdapter = MessengerAdapter()

    var image: String = ""
    var isEmoji: Boolean = true

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        EmojiManager.install(GoogleEmojiProvider())
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var preferences: PreferencesHelper

    override fun initialize() {
        setupRecycler()
    }

    private fun setupRecycler() = with(binding) {
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
        messengerRecycler.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        messengerRecycler.adapter = messAdapter
    }

    override fun setupListeners() {
        setupSendMessage()
    }

    private fun setupSendMessage() = with(binding) {
        btnSend.setOnSingleClickListener {
            viewModel.accountState.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
                when (it) {
                    is UIState.Error -> Log.e("naruto", it.error)
                    is UIState.Loading -> {}
                    is UIState.Success -> {
                        addParameters(this, it.data)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    private fun addParameters(binding: FragmentMessengerBinding, data: DocumentSnapshot) {
        val message = binding.etSendMessage.text.toString().trim()
        val senderId = preferences.userId
        val timeOfSend = getTimeUser("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss")
        val name = data.getString(Constants.KEY_NAME).toString()
        val profileImage = data.getString(Constants.KEY_IMAGE).toString()
        if (senderId != null) {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                viewModel.setParameters(
                    senderId,
                    name,
                    timeOfSend,
                    message,
                    "",
                    profileImage
                )
            }
        }
        binding.etSendMessage.setText("")
    }

    override fun setupObserves() {
        viewModel.messengerState.observeForever {
            lifecycleScope.launch {
                messAdapter.checkId(preferences.userId)
                messAdapter.submitData(it)
                binding.messengerRecycler.scrollToPosition(messAdapter.itemCount - 1)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun initFields()= with(binding) {
        etSendMessage.addTextChangedListener(AppTextWatcher {
            val string = etSendMessage.hint.toString()
            if (string.isEmpty() || string == "Запись") {
                btnSend.visibility = View.GONE
                btnGallery.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                btnMic.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                btnSend.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                btnGallery.visibility = View.GONE
                btnMic.visibility = View.GONE

            }
        })
        btnGallery.setOnClickListener {
            mGetContent.launch("image/*")
        }

    }

    val mGetContent = registerForActivityResult<String, Uri>(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri ->
        image = uri.toString()
        Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "изображение было выбранно", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
//        Glide.with(binding.imagePhotoMessage).load(image).centerCrop()
//            .into(binding.imagePhotoMessage)
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun sendVoice() = with(binding) {
            btnMic.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
                if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    etSendMessage.hint = "Запись"
                    btnGallery.visibility = View.GONE
                    btnMic.setColorFilter(
                        ContextCompat.getColor(
                            requireContext(),
                            R.color.design_default_color_primary_dark
                        )
                    )
                } else if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    etSendMessage.setText("")
                    btnGallery.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    btnMic.colorFilter = null
                }
                true
            }

    }

    override fun sendEmoji() {
        val popup = EmojiPopup.Builder.fromRootView(binding.root).build(binding.etSendMessage)

        binding.btnEmoticon.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            popup.toggle()
            val icon: Int
            if (isEmoji) {
                isEmoji = false
                icon = R.drawable.ic_keyboard
            } else {
                isEmoji = true
                icon = R.drawable.emoji
            }
            binding.btnEmoticon.setImageDrawable(
                ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(), icon)
            );

        })
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Приведите код, где именно View для фрагмента создается.